# How to make relationships in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, orm, relationship, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to make the relationship between the tables, but can’t figure out what I doing wrong.

I read The documentations in cakephp3, and tons of post in stackoverflow, and still can’t get any result.

```
         --------------------------
name    |invoices     |shares      |
var     |id           |id          |
var     |             |idBill      |
         --------------------------
```

The relationship should be from idBill in shares and id in invoices

```
class SharesTable extends Table {
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->belongsTo('invoices', [
        'className' => 'App\Model\Table\InvoicesTable',
        'foreignKey' => 'idBill',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'id'
        ]);
    }
}
```

And in controller try to print the bill associate to the share like this:

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $share = $this->Shares->get($id, [
      'contain' => []
    ]);
    var_dump( $share->invoices );

    $this->set('share', $share);
}
```

I just expect to print the bill but I always get null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `contain` is empty, so you won't receive any associations. Also the default entity property name for `belongsTo` (and `hasOne`) associations is the singular, underscored variant of the association name, ie `invoice`, not `invoices`.

It's also recommended to use association names that do match the table alias, that is `Invoices` (with a capital `I`) for `InvoicesTable`, that way it will find the class automatically and you don't have to specify it via the `className` option (also there is no `targetForeignKey` option for `belongsTo` associations).

```
$this->belongsTo('Invoices', [
    'foreignKey' => 'idBill'
]);
```

```
$share = $this->Shares->get($id, [
  'contain' => ['Invoices']
]);

debug($share->invoice);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Eager Loading Associations Via Contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)**